# How to hide `A::x` and expose `B::x` only in such a case?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, standards, name-lookup

```
namespace A
{
int a = 1;
int x = 2;
}

namespace B
{
int b = 3;
int x = 4;
}

using namespace A;
using namespace B;
using B::x;

int main()
{   
    return x; // error : reference to 'x' is ambiguous
}
```

**How to hide `A::x` and expose `B::x` only in such a case?**

Comment: `using B::x;` doesn't pick one. You already have both.

Comment: How to hide `A::x` and expose `B::x` only in such a case?

Comment: simple solution: Get rid of the `using namespace ...;`.  If you can't you should be able to move `using B::x;` into `main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

You brought both names into scope, and that's that.

To fix that, don't do that; avoid `using namespace`.

Comment: Provided that `A` and `B` both have many many different identifiers, except that a few ones are identical. Must I `using A::a1`, ``using A::a2`, ..., `using A::an`, `using B::b1`, ``using B::b2`, ..., `using B::bn`? How tedious it would be!

Comment: @xmllmx: You can do `using namespace A` in a narrower scope for convenience. Frankly it sounds like your namespaces are poorly laid out.

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace` brings that namespace into the current one.

Once you've done that you need to deal with any ambiguities yourself. Normally you use the scope resolution operator for that.

C++ doesn't give you the ability to un-bring in a namespace.

The best bet, by a country mile, is to avoid `using namespace` in the first place. Learn to love code containing lots of `::` operators.